# Key keeps the old name after renaming it

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
foreach ($all_orders as $order){//the $all_orders array contains a number of arrays, so it's a multidimensional array

$order["Order Rank"]=$order[0];
unset($order[0]);
}
```

after renaming the key with the new key and when i print the array:

```
print_r($all_orders);
```

i got the old key name (which is 0):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            )
```

why it's not :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ["Order Rank"] => 1
                )
```

am i missing something? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're modifying a *copy* of the element.

Use references:

```
foreach ($all_orders as &$order) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working with the $order variable, which is not the same as the array. You want to:

```
foreach ($all_orders as $key => $order){//the $all_orders array contains a number of arrays, so it's a multidimensional array

$all_orders[$key]["Order Rank"]=$order[0];
unset($all_orders[$key]);
}
```